# Convert 2D array into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

How can I convert this

```
[["name", "oni"], ["age",2]]
```

to

```
[{name:"oni"}, {age:2}]
```

Comment: Nice. Did you try anything?

Comment: Why not `{name: 'oni', age: 2}`? A much more useful data structure.

Comment: I need to iterate through the data for angular 5 data table. using *ngFor

Answer (score 6):

You can use `.map()` to iterate over array and returned value in desired (object) format:

```js
let data = [["name", "oni"], ["age",2]];

let result = data.map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is not what i want. I want [
  {
    name: "oni"
  },
  {
    age: 2
  }
]

Answer (score 2):

```js
new_array = your_array.map((entry)=>{
    return {[entry[0]]: entry[1]}
})
console.log(new_array)
```

Comment: This is not what i want. I want [ { name: "oni" }, { age: 2 } ]

Comment: This will give you the same result @valentine. 
[ { name: "oni" }, { age: 2 } ]

Comment: when i iterate through this using angular *ngFor is shows randomly on different rows. when it is suppose to be in a single row

Comment: @valentine can you share your snippet of what you are trying to do with ngFor?

Comment: Since the number of elements in the array are 2 the rows would be 2 itself and not 1. Maybe you need a different data structure.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the properties keys are unique why not create a single object with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead? A single object is much easier to manipulate than an array of objects with one property apiece.

```js
const arr = [["name", "oni"], ["age",2]];
const obj = arr.reduce((acc, c) => {
  acc[c[0]] = c[1];
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

Then just grab the values with dot notation: `obj.name`, for example.